# Grails Quartz Plugin error with jdbcStore

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin

I trying to use the latest quartz plugin from Grails : quartz:1.0.1.

It works if I leave the jdbcStore = false, fails if I set to true.
QuartzConfig.groovy:

```
    quartz {
       autoStartup = true
       jdbcStore = true
       waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true
       exposeSchedulerInRepository = false

    props {
        scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
     }
    }
```

Here is the property file:

```
    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName reporting_test
    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId AUTO

    org.quartz.threadPool.class org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount 5
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority 5

    org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold 60000

    org.quartz.jobStore.class org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
    org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate

    org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties false
    org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix QRTZ_
    org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered true
    org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval 5000

    org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
    org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown true
```

I have been trying to experiment with the Datasource setting as I would prefer to use my default DS set up in Datasource.groovy.  Regardless of settings for the datasource I still get the following error message on start up.

```
        2013-12-18 13:43:14,693 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]
        org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
        Caused by: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]
            at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:157)
            at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:113)
            at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:238)
            at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1086)
            at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.addJob(QuartzScheduler.java:969)
            at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.addJob(QuartzScheduler.java:958)
            at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.addJob(StdScheduler.java:268)
            at QuartzGrailsPlugin.scheduleJob(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy:268)
            at QuartzGrailsPlugin$_closure5_closure23.doCall(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy:248)
            at QuartzGrailsPlugin$_closure5.doCall(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy:247)
            ... 4 more
        Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
            at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:96)
            ... 13 more
```

The tables exist in my database.  I actually was using them with quartz2 plugin for grails, however for various reasons decided to try out this plugin.

Any ideas on what i am setting up incorrectly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer.

There is a query that is being run to lock the rows, in this case when failing it was:

```
SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'reporting_test' AND LOCK_NAME = 'STATE_ACCESS' FOR UPDATE
```

The FOR UPDATE does not work for MSSQL Database.  I found i was using the wrong delegate.  I switched  my property to:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
```

This worked, hope this helps someone else.

Comment: What do you mean "switched my property" ?

Comment: @KorayTugay In the configuration file for your quartz project, you will have settings that configure the quartz scheduler. He means that he changed these to utilize the `MSSQLDelegate`. I'm using quartz in a web project, so the property I need to change is found in my Web.config.

Comment: This is available in comments section of [Quartz SQL Script](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_sqlServer.sql), I missed to notice that at first sight